# Pages with filename ending with '... default.aspx' does not appear when searching in lists or using Content Search Webpart in SharePoint

Tags: search, sharepoint

I have a curious question regarding search on both SharePoint Online, 2016 and 2013 that I can not figure out myself. Both sites have publishing features enable.

Pages with filename ending with the text "default" - eg http://example.com/.../.../My-page-ending-with-default.aspx do not appear to be founded with search in lists, CSWP or normal sitecollection search. Pages are visible in the listview without search. The same goes for 'default.aspx'. I can see in Central admin that the pages are crawled successfully in the crawl log.

I have for example tried with "filename:'My-page-ending-with-default.aspx'" and "filename:'default.aspx'" but without success. Other pages work fine with "filename:'nameOfPage.aspx'". Normal search with the keyword 'default' also does not show pages that are either named 'default.aspx' or end with '... default.aspx' - only those with default in the middle of the file name is found.

Is 'default.aspx' somehow a reserved word that is excluded from search?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I could reproduce your issue if the page name ends with "Default".

[image]

It will only show the pages library result who store them, not the single page.

As a workaround, we suggest you add other words at the end, such as TestDefaultS:

[image]

Comment: Hi Julie_MSFT, thanks for the workaound, but I already know that :-) It just amazes me that there is no fix or explanation - we have an intranet where many users create pages and often see the problem.

Comment: For this situation, i think this is something by design behind SharePoint, you could open a ticket to Microsoft for detailed explanation.